# Size of div set to 386x104 in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I am facing an issue with ng-scope.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="suggestions1 in suggestions">

    <a href="{{suggestions1.link}}">
      <div class="notific">
          {{suggestions1.title}}
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Problem is my formatting is messed up. When I inspect the element I found this.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 ng-scope" ng-repeat="suggestions1 in suggestions">

    <a href="text.html#?id=27">
      <div class="notific">
          <h7 class="ng-binding">Test </h7>
      </div>
    </a>  
</div>
```

Size of div automatically set to 386x104. I checked entire css file it is not defined. Also I removed all the css elements but doesn't help.

When I checked the details of ng-scope in Chrome inspect I found **clientHeight
:104** is defined there.

How can I prevent it? I am using Bootstrap and Angular 1.

Comment: If I understand well, you think that the `ng-scope` class on the very first `div` is responsible for setting that undesired 386x104 value right ? Do you have a CodePen or jsFiddle in order to help you investigate that ?

Comment: The `ng-repeat` directive creates child scopes and sets an `ng-scope` class on elements with child scopes. That's the way the AngularJS framework works. Why is that a problem?

Comment: If `suggestions1.title` contains HTML, interpolation with `{{ }}` will not bind HTML tags. Instead use the `bind-as-html` directive.

Comment: Thanks All for your support. instead of div i used span thats fix the issue.